# unit testing with doctest in python 2.7

Tags: python

I just started programming in python and only gotten so far into functions. I have some experience in Java according to a course I took. So from what I understand, unit testing is good practice to test to see if functions are working properly. Here is a coding question I was given:

Click [here](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch05.html)

I have this so far:

```
def compare(a,b):
"""
  >>> compare(5,4)
  1
  >>> compare(7,7)
  0
  >>> compare(2,3)
  -1 
  >>> compare(42,1)
  1
"""

if a > b:
    return 1
elif a == b:
    return 0
elif a < b:
    return -1

if __name__== '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

File "ch05.py", line 7, in __main__.compare
Failed example:
              compare(2,3)
Expected:
-1
Got:
-1
```

What am I missing or how do I correct the code? I thought I was suppose to be using True/False Booleans not actual integers.

Comment: 7 == 7, so you have the wrong expected output.

Comment: The exercise you liked to quite clearly states "Write a compare function that returns `1` if `a > b`, `0` if `a == b`, and `-1` if `a < b`." You are returning `True`/`False` instead, which is why you are failing the exercise-setter's test. Doctest is working just fine, though!

Comment: I changed some things around and got the following above.. so the expected value and the got value are the same but why does the test still fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Sam said, comparisons are often represented by the integers 1 (greater than), 0 (equal to), -1 (less than). You need to modify your code to reflect this attribute.  Also, it may be easier if you follow the unittest conventions covered here https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html.  The logic is pretty easy to follow.

Also - not sure if this was a copy/paste error, but your indention is off.

Comment: Yes it is a copy/paste error thanks. And while looking through those conventions I think in this book that I'm studying they introduced unittest to early. It doesn't even mention conventions on them whereas it follows conventions with everything else so far.

Comment: It may be easier to just follow the example they give you (which helped me a lot). `setUp` happens before every test; it can be omitted.  `tearDown` happens after each test; it can also be omitted.  In each test use the assert- methods (which can be found in that same link I gave you) to check your results.  If you are having trouble with specifics or syntax, I'd be happy to look at it.  Regarding your above test, I am less familiar with `doctest` so I'm unable to explain why that is failing :/.  Good luck.